# Why I have this problem with PrimeNG FileUpload component related to the url parameter that referer to a page that doesn't exist

Tags: angular, primeng, javascript-framework

I am working on an Angular application using PrimeNG and I am finding some difficulties with the PrimeNG **FileUpload** component, this one: https://primefaces.org/primeng/showcase/#/fileupload

I was following the official documentation and source code example of this component but I have the following problem.

In my Angular component HTML code I put the same code provided by the example, something like this:

```
<div class="card">
  <h5>Advanced</h5>
  <p-fileUpload name="demo[]" url="./upload.php" (onUpload)="onUpload($event)"
                multiple="multiple" accept="image/*" maxFileSize="1000000">
          <ng-template pTemplate="content">
              <ul *ngIf="uploadedFiles.length">
                  <li *ngFor="let file of uploadedFiles">{{file.name}} - {{file.size}} bytes</li>
              </ul>
          </ng-template>
  </p-fileUpload>
</div>
```

And here I noticed the first "strange" thing. This component declare the **url="./upload.php"** parameter on the component definition. It seemed strange to me because this is an Angular application and I have to handle all into my Angular application.

Into this component officila documentation I can read this:

> FileUpload requires a url property as the upload target and a name to
> identify the files at backend.

What exactly means? Why? I have nothing related to a PHP application. It have all to be handled by my Angular component.

Backing to the code example then I put this array into my TypeScript code in order to contain the uploaded files:

```
uploadedFiles: any[] = [];
```

and the following method to handle the actual file upload feature (that I think will be triggered when the user click on the Update button):

```
onUpload(event) {
    console.log("onUpload() START");
    for(let file of event.files) {
        console.log("FILE TO BE UPLOADED: ", file);
        this.uploadedFiles.push(file);
    }

    this.messageService.add({severity: 'info', summary: 'File Uploaded', detail: ''});
}
```

Running my application now I can select files to be uploaded:

[image]

The problem now is that clicking on the **Update** button happens something strange (as I expected due to the presence of the **url="./upload.php"** paremeter in the HTML definition of this upload component).

Clicking on the Update button the **onUpload(event)** defined in my TypeScript code is not executed and I obtain the following error into my Chrome console:

```
zone-evergreen.js:2845 POST http://localhost:4200/upload.php 404 (Not Found)
```

It seems that the PrimeNG FileUpload component is trying to perform an HTTP POST call toward the URL specified by the **url** parameter that doesn't exist in my application (and that have not to exist).

Why? What am I missing? How can I handle this situation in order that the entire operation is handled by my TypeScript component code? (the idea is that when the Upload button is clicked the **onUpload()** method is called and then the file will be saved on Firebase Storage with my custom code). How can I fix it?

Answer (score 4):

I think that I solved it by myself using the "Custom Upload" as shown in the doc:

1. In the HTML code of my component:

   ###### Advanced

   ```
    <p-fileUpload name="myfile[]" customUpload="true" (uploadHandler)="myUploader($event)">

                multiple="multiple" accept="image/*" maxFileSize="1000000">
          <ng-template pTemplate="content">
              <ul *ngIf="uploadedFiles.length">
                  <li *ngFor="let file of uploadedFiles">{{file.name}} - {{file.size}} bytes</li>
              </ul>
          </ng-template>
    </p-fileUpload>
   ```
2. In my TypeScript code:

   ```
    myUploader(event) {
      console.log("onUpload() START");
      for(let file of event.files) {
        console.log("FILE TO BE UPLOADED: ", file);
        this.uploadedFiles.push(file);
      }
      this.messageService.add({severity: 'info', summary: 'File Uploaded', detail: ''});
    }
   ```